# Getting the most recent row and linking it with another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to get the most recent row of a table

```
user_quiz:
+--------+-----------+-------------+-------------------+------------+
|quiz_id |userid     | module_id   |number_of_questions| user_score |     
+--------+-----------+-------------+-------------------+-------- ---+
|    1   |  1        |      1      |        5          |     5      |
|    2   |  2        |      2      |        10         |     9      |
|    3   |  1        |      1      |        10         |     9      |
+--------+-----------+-------------+-------------------+------------+
```

I have used the query:

```
SELECT * FROM user_quiz WHERE userid = 1 ORDER BY quiz_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

which correctly retrieves the last row. 
However I want to link the module_id with another table:

```
    module:
    +---------+------------+
    |module_id|module_name |    
    +---------+------------+
    |    1    |  Forces    | 
    |    2    | Electricity|   
    +---------+------------+
```

And retrieve the module name.

The result of the query will be used to print out the users most recent quiz:

```
Most recent quiz: Forces - Number of questions: 10 - User Score: 9
```

Is this possible using just one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT uq.*, m.module_name
FROM user_quiz uq JOIN
     modules m
     ON uq.module_id = m.module_id
WHERE uq.userid = 1
ORDER BY uq.quiz_id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: could you explain where the abbreviations come from in the query please?

Comment: @Zestyy99 . . . Those are table aliases and an important part of the SQL language.

Answer (score 1):

A more simple query to achieve the same would be

```
SELECT 
     user_quiz.quiz_id, 
     user_quiz.number_of_questions, 
     user_quiz.user_score, 
     modules .module_name
FROM user_quiz JOIN modules
     ON user_quiz.module_id = modules.module_id
WHERE user_quiz.userid = 1
ORDER BY user_quiz.quiz_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If you want to get the same results for all the users, you could use a bit more sophisticated query

```
SELECT
    user_quiz_virtual_table.userid,
    user_quiz_virtual_table.quiz_id, 
    user_quiz_virtual_table.number_of_questions, 
    user_quiz_virtual_table.user_score, 
    modules.module_name
FROM (
    SELECT 
      user_quiz.userid
      user_quiz.quiz_id, 
      user_quiz.module_id
      user_quiz.number_of_questions, 
      user_quiz.user_score
    FROM user_quiz
    ORDER BY user_quiz.quiz_id DESC
    GROUP BY userid
) AS user_quiz_virtual_table
JOIN modules ON user_quiz_virtual_table.module_id = modules.module_id
```